# CSS conflict with Flexslider2

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, flexslider

When I load the script for flexslider2 my slider images work as expected -- then when I load the flexslider2 styles to complete the setup, the images in slider disappear and the nav dots are just a vertical line down the side.

I've tried so many things in the last few hours -- disabling plugins, disabling all scripts -- now the only script I have loading is jquery and the flexsider.

here is the link
please help with this perplexing issue!

[link][1]

Comment: .header-image in style.css:673 hay have something to do.

Comment: I'm baffled, I will look later and try again, I just wanted to say I live right near you guys!

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply -- yes, Gabriel, you're right, .header-image was the culprit -- somehow that kept eluding me even though I removed the class on the div - I just simply didn't set the widths correctly for the slider div and the content div floating next to it. again - thank you both for your reply. To let such a small issue create havoc, and how much time!